# I am trying to download QGIS Essen

Tags: qgis

I am trying to download QGIS Essen. I run the application and it says it has installed the program but it hasn't. I am using windows 7 and have previously downloaded QGIS successfully on another computer. Does anyone know why it would not be installing?

Comment: Please give a bit more detail as to what has happened and what you've tried.  It's hard to diagnose a problem from "it says it has installed the program but it hasn't."

Comment: uninstall, reinstall then restart your computer

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a registry clean with CCleaner? That might help (and reboot afterwards). Also check that the program is not installed through your 'programs and features'.